# Where to set the range of the spell Thail Smash for Sindragosa

Tags: azerothcore

I need to know where I can change the range of the spell - THAIL SMASH 71077

the only thing i can see in the C++ code regarding this spell is this:

```
events.ScheduleEvent(EVENT_TAIL_SMASH, 20000, EVENT_GROUP_LAND_PHASE);
```

From: 
https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/scripts/Northrend/IcecrownCitadel/boss_sindragosa.cpp#L331

The main problem is that this spell have a main effect that is activated at 45 and 2 secondary effect that are activaded at 20 yard , but in game the secondary effects of the spell are actived at more than 20 yard, how i can resolve this ?

https://www.wowhead.com/spell=71077/tail-smash

Comment: server/game/Spells/SpellMgr.cpp:5613:        case 71077: // Tail Smash (Sindragosa)
server/scripts/Northrend/IcecrownCitadel/boss_sindragosa.cpp:39:    SPELL_TAIL_SMASH            = 71077,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you remember but, when you extracted maps, mmaps and vmaps, you also extracted some files called "DBC".
These files are extracted from the client as well as the rest of the map files.

This means that every spell is "hard coded" into these files. Their effects, visuals and whatnot are not viable to modify because if you did and you lost these files, you would lose a lot of progress. If you extract new DBCs you would obviously not have these files. And so wouldn't other contributors.

So to fix this, there's a C++ file called SpellMgr.cpp in which people have been modifying spell attributes.

On this specific file, you have the spell you are looking for:

https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/game/Spells/SpellMgr.cpp#L5624

They are already correcting the available targets for this spell with

```
spellInfo->EffectImplicitTargetA[0] = TARGET_DEST_CASTER_BACK;
```

So to get your expected results you would need to change the Radius of effect with a line like this one:

```
spellInfo->EffectRadiusIndex[1] = 20; // Spell effect 1 radius to 20y
spellInfo->EffectRadiusIndex[2] = 20; // Spell effect 2 radius to 20y
```